# Is there a rough approximation for the function of the average number of divisors of a number?

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

Sorry if my title is a little confusing. Maybe someone can correct it. Anyway, assume a function f(x), which would equal the sum of the amount of divisors of all numbers less than or equal to x, divided by x. So f(1) would equal 1, f(2) would equal 3/2, f(3) would equal 5/3, f(4) and f(5) would both equal 3, and so on.

I plotted this function using Excel and got something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMLbx.jpg). It seems to represent a logarithmic function. Would there be a neat way to represent this function in terms of logarithms? What if we used the median instead and not the average? Would that change the function?

Comment: Something else I thought was interesting about this function was that some, but not all integers, are values of f(x). For example, f(x) = 7 for x = 930, and f(x) = 9 for x = 6937 and x = 6947. There are no values for which f(x) = 8 though.

Comment: For $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sigma_0(k)$, $f(4)=f(5)=2$ and $f(2548)=8$.

Comment: Oh my. I checked the data again and it looks like f(2548) is indeed equal to 8.

Anyway, I'm not very familiar with many of these notations. In the formula you answered below, I'm assuming gamma represents the Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Comment: Yes, $\gamma \approx 0.577216$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant, and $\sigma_k(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} d^k$, so $\sigma_0(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} d^0=\sum\limits_{d|n} 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sigma_0(k)\approx\log (n)+2 \gamma -1$$

See formula (40) at [Divisor Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) and the related [Dirichlet Divisor Problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletDivisorProblem.html).